# What does add_lvalue_reference do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class that makes a path for a montecarlo simulator where it takes creates paths of integers from an array of available ints. So for example we could have a path of length 3 drawn from the array containing {0,1,2,3,4} and this would for example generate 3,1,2 and 1,4,0.

```
//This path generator just generates a list of ints for each path
template< typename randgen >
class MCPathGen {
    public:
        typedef vector< int > mcpath_t;
        typedef randgen randgen_t;
        typedef typename add_lvalue_reference<randgen>::type randgen_ref_t;

        MCPathGend(randgen_ref_t r) : m_rgen(r) {}

        //generate a single path by shuffling a copy of blank_d
        mcpath_t operator()() {
            Chooser< randgen_t > choose(m_rgen);
            mcpath_t path_temp(blank_d.begin(), blank_d.end());
            random_shuffle(path_temp.begin(), path_temp.end(), choose);

            return path_temp;
        };

    private:
        randgen_ref_t m_rgen;

};
```

Now I'm not quite sure what my colleague has done by using `typedef typename add_lvalue_reference<randgen>::type randgen_ref_t;`

What does add_lvalue_reference do?
Is this necessary for making the code work?

I have not seen this before, so any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Ask your colleague why they did it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying pseudo-random number generators means you'd get the same stream of "random" numbers from each, which is not desirable, so you need a reference there.

However, **you could just say `randgen&`.**

According to `[dcl.ref]` in draft 3225, just `randgen&` will create an lvalue reference no matter what's passed in (type, lvalue-reference-type, or rvalue-reference-type), so I'd just use that.

Quote from the standard that controls this behavior:

> If a *typedef* (7.1.3), a type *template-parameter* (14.3.1), or a *decltype-speciﬁer* (7.1.6.2) denotes a type **`TR`** that is a reference to a type **`T`**, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* **`TR`**” creates the type
>   “lvalue reference to **`T`**”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* **`TR`**” creates the type **`TR`**.
>
> [ Example:

```
int  i;
typedef  int&  LRI;
typedef  int&&  RRI;

LRI&  r1  =  i; // r1 has the type int&
const  LRI&  r2  =  i; // r2 has the type int&
const  LRI&&  r3  =  i; // r3 has the type int&

RRI&  r4  =  i; // r4 has the type int&
RRI&&  r5  =  i; // r5 has the type int&&

decltype(r2)&  r6  =  i; // r6 has the type int&
decltype(r2)&&  r7  =  i; // r7 has the type int&
```

> — end example ]

From section `[meta.trans.ref]`:

> `template <class T> struct add_lvalue_reference;`
>   If **`T`** names an object or function type then the member typedef `type`
>   shall name **`T&`**; otherwise, if **`T`** names a type “rvalue reference to **`T1`**” then
>   the member typedef `type` shall name **`T1&`**; otherwise, type shall name **`T`**.

They are exactly the same thing.

In C++03, they're the same thing too.  From `[type.arg.type]`:

> If a template-argument for a template-parameter **`T`** names a type “reference to *cv1* **`S`**”, an attempt to create the type
>   “reference to *cv2* **`T`**” creates the type “reference to *cv12* **`S`**”, where *cv12* is the union of the cv-qualiﬁers *cv1* and *cv2*.
>   Redundant cv-qualiﬁers are ignored.
>
> [ Example:

```
template   < class  T >  class   X  {
void   f( const   T &);
/ ∗ . . . ∗ /
};
X< int & >  x;          / / X<int&>::f has the parameter type const  int&
```

> — end example ]

Comment: @shuttle87: What if `randgen` is Rvalue Reference? Then `randgen&` would be an error. And in case if you don't know what rvalue reference is, `int &&` is an rvalue reference. See my answer and the links posted over there!

Comment: PRNGs are not copyable? What PRNGs are you talking about?

Comment: thanks for elaborating. So it seems that C++0x obsoletes the `add_lvalue_reference` which is kept for people who are used to it

Comment: @sellibitze: Ok, I looked in the standard and they are.  The point is you don't WANT to use a copy.