# Difference between & and std::add_lvalue_reference

Tags: c++, templates, stl

while reading some SO questions regarding c++ templates and generally code I did not write I came across using such construct:

```
template<class T>
std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T> my_foo(T &t) { /*do some stuff and return*/ }
```

On the other hand I have been always using something like this:

```
template<class T>
T &my_foo(T &t) { /*do some stuff and return*/ }
```

And so I have a few questions:

1. Are these snippets of code equivalent?
2. If not, what is the difference between them?
3. If not, which is to be prefered?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108295/5212827. Might be a duplicate.

Comment: You can infer the difference through a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference).